# Show/ Hide Table Column with colspan using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a HTML table as shown in http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/auny3/ .  The table has 10 columns – divided into three col groups.  I need to hide/show the colgroup named “Associate Info” (including its rows data)  using buttons “Show Associate” and “Hide Associate”.

What is the best way (in terms of performance) for doing this using jQuery?

Please answer if you have a better answer than http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/auny3/8/

Note: I am generating the table using ASP.Net GridView as given in 
http://www.sacdeveloper.com/Community/Articles/tabid/86/ctl/ArticleView/mid/458/articleId/1/Group_columns_in_an_ASPNet_Gridview.aspx

**Reference**:

1. http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/auny3/8/
2. http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/auny3/12/
3. http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/auny3/11/
4. http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/auny3/13/

**Selected Answer**

1. http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/UqdQp/2/

[image]

Comment: can u change your html if yes than it's possbile with jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have generalized the idea provided by @Pioul. Hence please upvote for @Pioul also if you like this answer.  This generalized approach is available in http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/UqdQp/10/

References:

1. [Finding column index using jQuery when table contains column-spanning cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166452/finding-column-index-using-jquery-when-table-contains-column-spanning-cells/12472926#12472926)
2. [Select table cells based on the value in the cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471642/select-table-cells-based-on-the-value-in-the-cell)

CODE

```
var associateStartElementString = "EmpID";
var financialStartElementString = "Type";

var associateHTMLElements;
var financialHTMLElements;

var associateHideClass = '.tableColGroupAssociate';
var financialHideClass = '.tableColGroupTransaction';

$(document).ready(function () {



////////Hide Sections


//Associate Hide
$('.associateHide').live("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();


    var hideClass = associateHideClass; 
    associateHTMLElements = HideSection(hideClass, associateStartElementString);

    $('.btnAssociate').show();

});

//Financial Hide
$('.financialHide').live("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

  var hideClass = financialHideClass ;

    financialHTMLElements = HideSection(hideClass, financialStartElementString);

    $('.btnFinancial').show();

});


////SHOW 
$('.btnAssociate').click(function()
{
    associateHTMLElements.show();

      var firstHeaderLineElement = $(".resultGridTable").find(associateHideClass );

    firstHeaderLineElement.show(); 

});


$('.btnFinancial').click(function()
{
    financialHTMLElements.show();

      var firstHeaderLineElement = $(".resultGridTable").find(financialHideClass );

    firstHeaderLineElement.show(); 

});



//Function 1
function HideSection(hideClass, startElementString) 
{

var htmlElement = GetTableSections(hideClass, startElementString);

var firstHeaderLineElement = $(".resultGridTable").find(hideClass);

var variableToSet;

if (!(htmlElement === undefined)) {

    variableToSet = htmlElement;
    htmlElement.hide();
    firstHeaderLineElement.hide();
}

return variableToSet;
}


//Function 2
function GetTableSections(hideClass, referenceHeaderCellValue) {


var firstHeaderLineElement = $(".resultGridTable").find(hideClass);
var colspan = parseInt(firstHeaderLineElement.attr("colspan"));


var startElementIndex = GetNonColSpanIndex(referenceHeaderCellValue);


if (startElementIndex > 0) {

    startElementIndex = (startElementIndex - 1);

    var selectedElements = $("tr:gt(0)")
                                    .find("th:gt(" + startElementIndex + "):lt(" + colspan + "), td:gt(" + startElementIndex + "):lt(" + colspan + ")");

    return selectedElements;

}


}

//Function 3
function GetNonColSpanIndex(referenceHeaderCellValue) {


var selectedCell = $("th").filter(function (i) {
    return ($.trim($(this).html())) == referenceHeaderCellValue;


});


var allCells = $(selectedCell).parent('tr').children();
var normalIndex = allCells.index($(selectedCell));
var nonColSpanIndex = 0;


allCells.each(
    function (i, item) {
        if (i == normalIndex)
            return false;

        var colspan = $(selectedCell).attr('colspan');
        colspan = colspan ? parseInt(colspan) : 1;
        nonColSpanIndex += colspan;
    }
    );

return nonColSpanIndex;
};


}
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi now used to this

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#show").click(function(){
    $("#showhide").show();
    });



    $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("#showhide").hide();
    });
})
```

and some change to your html

***[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/auny3/6/)***

Comment: It works. However, I won't be able to use it. I am generating the table using GridView. Wrapping the table columns inside a table may not be feasible. Can you suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use `nth-child` selector:

```
$('input').click(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Hide Associate"){
    $('th:nth-child(2), td:nth-child(2), th:nth-child(3):not(:first), td:nth-child(3), th:nth-child(4), td:nth-child(4), th:nth-child(5), td:nth-child(5)').hide();
    }else{
        $('th:nth-child(2), td:nth-child(2), th:nth-child(3):not(:first), td:nth-child(3), th:nth-child(4), td:nth-child(4), th:nth-child(5), td:nth-child(5)').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to apply to other section also. That didn't work. What need to be changed to make it work? http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/auny3/9/

Comment: @Lijo in the else statement change `hide` to `show`and to hide the "Associate Info" add `th:nth-child(3):first` in the selectors. See [This](http://jsfiddle.net/alex_ball/auny3/10/)

Answer (score 2):

Here, working with your current HTML, and will keep working if your Associate Info header ever stored more columns (the script is looking for its `colspan` attribute to fetch the appropriate number of columns).

```
$("input").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var label = $(".resultGridTable .tableColGroupAssociate"),
        colspan = parseInt(label.attr("colspan"), 10),
        associate = $("tr:gt(0)")
                        .find("th:gt(0):lt("+ colspan +"), td:gt(0):lt("+ colspan +")")
                        .add(label);

    if($(this).val() == 'Hide Associate') associate.hide();
        else associate.show();
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pioul/UqdQp/1/)

Comment: Can you please explain how it works? I am confused about ".add(label)"

Comment: It's storing every element we want to hide or show into the `associate` object. It first stores columns 1 to 4 from lines 1 to 3, and then adds ([jQuery.add](http://api.jquery.com/add/)) to those elements the "Associate Info" cell. That way, we have every element we want to work with in a single jQuery object: `associate`.

Comment: Thanks. So, you are using zero based indexing in the above explanation. Also, the variable name "label" can be renamed as  "firstLine".

Comment: I have posted a generalized approach as answer. Please provide your thoughts